# How to check if MYSQL field is null and replace with current timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using a [Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) and got a database with different `pid`s (personal ids) and a field `activatedValue` which is already set to `NULL` or the [`current_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/).

I got the `pid` and need to find its `activatedValue`-value. Than if the field is `NULL`, I want to replace it with `current_time()`. I thought about something like this:

```
$pid = '52'; // example for a personal id
$activatedValue = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT activatedValue FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '$pid'" );

if( is_null($activatedValue) ) {
  // replace activatedValue in database with current time
}
```

*How can I do this?*

---

There are several problems for me in achieving this. I have tried this:

```
$pid = '52';

if ( ! empty ( $pid ) ) {

  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "prelaunchr";
  $activatedValue = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT activated FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '$pid'" );

  if ( is_null($activatedValue) ) {
    $currentTime = current_time();
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET activated = NOW() WHERE pid = '$pid'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the value in the database record, you will need to run an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement, using [wpdb::query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/).

```
if( is_null($example_field) ) {
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET example_field = NOW() WHERE pid = '$pid'");
}
```

Comment: This is a suggestion of how to retrieve the current value right? Do you although got a suggestion of how to replace this value with the current timestamp? This is the most important part for me!

Comment: see revised answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @samonela, I see that you understood my problem. I have updated my answer to my current code, which does not work. The field still shows `NULL` after running the code. Can I check somehow if the code runned successful?

Comment: oh right - sorry I should have looked up current_time() to ensure it was a function before posting that; you can use `now()` or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: `current_time();` is a function indeed, you can check it right here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/

Comment: right - my example was using that as if it was a mySQL function, not a php/wordpress function...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify the DB and instead of using timestamp use datetime, then:

```
$pid = '52';

if ( ! empty ( $pid ) ) {

  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "prelaunchr";
  $activatedValue = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT activated FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '$pid'" );

  if ( is_null($activatedValue) ) {
    //Here you can change the TimeZone of the system//
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $date = date('Y/m/d h:i:s', time());
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET activated = '{$date}' WHERE pid = '$pid'");
  }
}
```